# Optimize SQL connection?

Tags: javascript, sql, database-connection

I am building a multi-page web project in HTML and Javascript  that is constantly reading from AND writing to an SQL database.  I can connect to the database and successfully run my project with this type of connection.

```
var connection = new ActiveXObject("ADODB.Connection") ;
var connectionstring="Data Source=<server>;Initial Catalog=<catalog>;User ID=<user>;   
Password=<password>;Provider=SQLOLEDB";
connection.Open(connectionstring);
var rs = new ActiveXObject("ADODB.Recordset");

rs.Open("SELECT * FROM table", connection);
rs.MoveFirst
while(!rs.eof)
{
   document.write(rs.fields(1));
   rs.movenext;
}

rs.close;
connection.close;
```

Works great and runs fine.  BUT, the first 5 lines (from var connection = to var rs =) causes the whole browser to freeze for a few seconds while it establishes the connection.  I need to speed that up since I am constantly connecting to the database throughout my project.  Is there a more effective way of connecting to a SQL database? or is my computer just bad and this should run faster?

Comment: Is there a reason why you're doing this client-side rather than server-side? Also, are you aware that this will ONLY work in IE?

Answer (score 3):

Javascript normally runs in the browser in a single thread - that means that if something takes time, no more javascript will run until the long running process finished running.

The normal way to deal with this is to have your database interactions on the *server* side using a server side language, and not in the client side.

Consider writing your data access logic on the server side returning some sort of structured object (XML and [JSON](http://www.json.org/) notations are popular) and using [AJAX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29) to retrieve and display the data.